How to Remove Unnecessary Slashes in Symfony Routing Generated Links
Symfony routing 5.4.48 (Without framework)
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator;

$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add('product_list', new Route(
    '/products/{_locale}/{category}/{brand}.html',
    [
        '_locale' => '',   // Default value _locale
        'brand' => ''     // Default value brand
    ],
    [
        '_locale' => 'en|ua|',       // regexp _locale (ua en or none)
        'category' => '[a-z0-9-]+',   // required category
        'brand' => '[a-z0-9-]*'      // brand (allow empty)
    ]
));

$context = new RequestContext('/');

$generator = new UrlGenerator($routes, $context);

echo $generator->generate('product_list', [
    '_locale' => null,
    'category' => 'electronics',
    'brand' => null,
]);

The result of this code will be /products//electronics/.html
But it should be /products/electronics.html
How can I remove slashes?

Those slashes are part of the route as you defined it. It's simply that the default values for _locale and brand are empty strings, exactly as you defined them.
